# add current time with text input

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCIWW.png) Iam new with react native,so maybe my question seems silly to all excepts.I want to add current time in text input.(i designd todo app,that show the todo list,now i want to show time in todo list,for eg i enter todo(complete frontend)and add,that contain complete and delete button,now i want to add time in that(task adding time).my code are following below,

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const COLORS = {primary: '#1f145c', white: '#fff'};
const App = () => {
  const \[todos, setTodos\] = React.useState(\[\]);
  const \[textInput, setTextInput\] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getTodosFromUserDevice();
  }, \[\]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    saveTodoToUserDevice(todos);
  }, \[todos\]);

  const addTodo = () => {
    if (textInput == '') {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please input todo');
    } else {
      const newTodo = {
        id: Math.random(),
        task: textInput,
        completed: false,
      };
      setTodos(\[...todos, newTodo\]);
      setTextInput('');
    }
  };

  const saveTodoToUserDevice = async todos => {
    try {
      const stringifyTodos = JSON.stringify(todos);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', stringifyTodos);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getTodosFromUserDevice = async () => {
    try {
      const todos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('todos');
      if (todos != null) {
        setTodos(JSON.parse(todos));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const markTodoComplete = todoId => {
    const newTodosItem = todos.map(item => {
      if (item.id == todoId) {
        return {...item, completed: true};
      }
      return item;
    });

    setTodos(newTodosItem);
  };

  const deleteTodo = todoId => {
    const newTodosItem = todos.filter(item => item.id != todoId);
    setTodos(newTodosItem);
  };

  const clearAllTodos = () => {
    Alert.alert('Confirm', 'Clear todos?', \[
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        onPress: () => setTodos(\[\]),
      },
      {
        text: 'No',
      },
    \]);
  };

  const ListItem = ({todo}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: COLORS.primary,
              textDecorationLine: todo?.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
            }}>
            {todo?.task}
          </Text>
        </View>
        {!todo?.completed && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => markTodoComplete(todo.id)}>
            <View style={\[styles.actionIcon, {backgroundColor: 'green'}\]}>
              <Icon name="done" size={20} color="white" />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>
          <View style={styles.actionIcon}>
            <Icon name="delete" size={20} color="white" />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      }}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            color: COLORS.primary,
          }}>
          TODO APP
        </Text>
        <Icon name="delete" size={25} color="red" onPress={clearAllTodos} />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{padding: 20, paddingBottom: 100}}
        data={todos}
        renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem todo={item} />}
      />

      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            value={textInput}
            placeholder="Add Todo"
            onChangeText={text => setTextInput(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={addTodo}>
          <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <Icon name="add" color="white" size={30} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    elevation: 40,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
    elevation: 40,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  listItem: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    elevation: 12,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  actionIcon: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginLeft: 5,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});

export default App;][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**i got the answer ,answer is following below,**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const COLORS = {primary: '#1f145c', white: '#fff'};
const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getTodosFromUserDevice();
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    saveTodoToUserDevice(todos);
  }, [todos]);

  const addTodo = () => {
    if (textInput == '') {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please input todo');
    } else {
      
      const newTodo = {
        id: Math.random(),
        task: textInput,
        completed: false,
        time: getCurrentTime()
      };
      setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
      setTextInput('');
    }
  };

  const saveTodoToUserDevice = async todos => {
    try {
      const stringifyTodos = JSON.stringify(todos);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', stringifyTodos);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getTodosFromUserDevice = async () => {
    try {
      const todos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('todos');
      if (todos != null) {
        setTodos(JSON.parse(todos));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  ***const getCurrentTime = () => {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    let dateTime = date + '/' + time;
    return dateTime;
  }***

  const markTodoComplete = todoId => {
    const newTodosItem = todos.map(item => {
      if (item.id == todoId) {
        return {...item, completed: true};
      }
      return item;
    });

    setTodos(newTodosItem);
  };

  const deleteTodo = todoId => {
    const newTodosItem = todos.filter(item => item.id != todoId);
    setTodos(newTodosItem);
  };

  const clearAllTodos = () => {
    Alert.alert('Confirm', 'Clear todos?', [
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        onPress: () => setTodos([]),
      },
      {
        text: 'No',
      },
    ]);
  };
  const comdel = () => {
    Alert.alert('select status', 'Complete or Delete', [
      {
        text: 'Delete',
        onPress: () => setTodos([]),
      },
      {
        text: 'Complete',
        onPress: () => {markTodoComplete(todo.id)}
      },
    ]);
  };

  const ListItem = ({todo}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: COLORS.primary,
              textDecorationLine: todo?.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
            }}>
            {todo?.task}
          </Text>
        </View>
        {/* {!todo?.completed && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => markTodoComplete(todo.id)}>
            <View style={[styles.actionIcon, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
              <Icon name="done" size={20} color="white" />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )} */}
        {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>
          <View style={styles.actionIcon}>
            <Icon name="delete" size={20} color="white" />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
        <View>
          <Text>
            {todo?.time}
           </Text>
        </View>
        <Icon name="menu" size={40} color="#a9a9a9" onPress={comdel} />
      </View>
      
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      }}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            color: COLORS.primary,
          }}>
          TODO APP
        </Text>
        <Icon name="delete" size={25} color="red" onPress={comdel} />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{padding: 20, paddingBottom: 100}}
        data={todos}
        renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem todo={item} />}
      />

      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            value={textInput}
            placeholder="Add Todo"
            onChangeText={text => setTextInput(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={addTodo}>
          <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <Icon name="add" color="white" size={30} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    elevation: 40,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
    elevation: 40,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  listItem: {
    padding: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
    flexDirection: 'column',
    elevation: 12,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  actionIcon: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginLeft: 5,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});

export default App;
```